# Reason behind weird black screen whenever turning on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display

Whenever i turn on my **windows 7** machine i get this weird black screen for around 5 to 6 secs
[This black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqZOC.jpg)

After this the windows boot normally.
I don't know what is the **reason** of this screen OR is there any problem with my hardware/software ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your video card driver (AMD, nV or intel) and make sure you do not have too many things running at start-up.

Comment: I think this solved my problem.

Comment: pls tick my question..since it was a genuine problem